# ANSI date (COBOL Integer date) to current date

Tags: javascript, date

I need to translate an integer representing the number of days since 01.01.1601 (as of 6th November 2012: 150422) to a javascript `Date` object.

Each year has approximately `365.242199` days, so the calculation should be as follows:

```
var daysPerYear = 365.242199;
var daysSince = 150422;

var year = 1601 + Math.floor(daysSince / daysPerYear); // correct, gives me 2012
var days = Math.floor(daysSince % daysPerYear); // wrong, gives me 307
```

Now I create the `Date` object:

```
var date = new Date(year, 0);
date.setDate(days);
```

The `date` now points to `'Fri Nov 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'` which is off by about 4 days.

What is wrong with my calculation? Is there an easier way to obtain the `Date` object?

Comment: was able to get closer with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qNcyU/), are you sure your `daysSince` number is correct?

Comment: @jbabey: I got it from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Alternatives

Comment: `Math.floor(((new Date()) - (new Date('1/1/1601')))/1000/60/60/24)` gives me 150424 as of right now.

Comment: Note that on the Wikipedia page you site, the ANSI date epoch has an origin of 1, rather than 0 (like JavaScript Date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript dates revolve from midnight on 1st January, 1970. If you do `new Data().getTime()`, for example, you'll be returned the number of milliseconds from that point. Therefore, to convert your dates from 1st January, 1601, you need to calculate the exact number of milliseconds between 1/1/1601 and 1/1/1970 and take the difference from your date (also converted into milliseconds).

This way, all you are doing is adding numbers together and won't suffer from any floating point inaccuracies or error from your approximations.

Answer (score 1):

Clone out a copy of OpenCOBOL 1.1, and look through **libcob/intrinsic.c** for computations.

See **cob_intr_date_of_integer** in particular.

For an SVN readonly checkout

```
svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/open-cobol/code/trunk open-cobol-code
```

or browse to

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/files/open-cobol/1.1/open-cobol-1.1.tar.gz/download
```

Comment: thanks for your hint, I didn't know that there was a C implementation of it. I already solved the issue otherwise, but this is still a good hint.